# How to use a while loop to iterate through a word inputed by user to find the indexes of each letter

Tags: swift

I'm new to swift programming and struggling with a simple method that I want to use. Ive added random letters to an array and I want a user to type in a word. The method should then iterate through each letter of that word and return the index of each letter so it would output a number code for the word. Eg. If I input "swift" it should return "185103", number relevant to the position of each letter though. (See my array). At the moment it has no loop so it's only returning one index for one letter. Here is what I have so far:

```
print("Please enter the word:")

if let inputCode = readLine(){

let pidgeonCode = ["s", "a", "t", "p", "i", "n", "m", "w", "g", "f", "c", "k"]
let location = pidgeonCode.index(of:inputCode)
print("Your word is: \(location!)")

} else{
print("Type something!!")

}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: How it can be possible like "swift" has five characters and you want "185103" which is actually six characters?

Comment: If you look at the index numbers of the characters, "f" has an index of 10. Hence 1 = "s", 8 = "w", 5 = "i", 10 = "f", 3 = "t".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, thanks. Here is the code I used for future help.

```
print("Please enter the word:")
if let inputCode = readLine(){
let numberOf = inputCode.count
var loop = 0
let pidgeonCode = ["@", "s", "a", "t", "p", "i", "n", "m", "d", "g", "o", "c", "k"]
var wordcode = "Code:"

while loop < numberOf{
    let x = inputCode.index(inputCode.startIndex, offsetBy: loop)
    let result = inputCode[x]
    let location = pidgeonCode.index(of:"\(result)")
    wordcode = wordcode + "\(location!)"
    loop = loop + 1
}
print(wordcode)

} else{
print("Type something!!")
}
```